# Water draining out of pipe when usage is high.

Tags: basement, toilet, drain, water-pressure

We moved into an old house and there is something happening in the basement that I need some help explaining.

Here is a image showing where the leak is happening. I've marked where the water is coming out of with red circle.

[image]

The water drips out of there when I flush a toilet multiple times and also turn on water in the kitchen. I believe the water is dripping because the water being drained is too much (just a guess). Because water does not drip when I flush rarely. It certainly has something to do with usage.

The top part of this pipe is shown in this image.

[image]

The top part is connected to a water filter (or softner). But here is the image of what it is being connected to

[image]

I called a plumber to come take a look and he is convinced that if that 2 inch pipe is made into a 3 inch pipe then that will solve the issue. But I think that might be just a temporary issue....If I use the water too much then it will again drip right?

Also, this problem started happening recently when I changed the toilet. The old toilet used more water and the new one uses less water but sends it down with more pressure. Could that be what triggered the issue?

What would be a long term solution for this?

Comment: Something isn't clear to me here... That flexible Plastic line (brine effluent from the softener?) looks like the only thing connected to that pvc drain. Where are the drain inlets from the toilet and sink?

Comment: Yes, that is the only thing connected to the pvc. In the first image, the black pipes on the left and right of the PVC are what is draining the toilet and the sink.

Comment: OK. I'm not sure why there should ever be a problem there, but I would probably just seal the leaking part... Is it a threaded pvc cap there? If so, I'd just unthread it and seal the threads up. Pvc is easy enough to replace should you need to access that port in the future.

Comment: yeah, but I'm not sure whether that is a long term fix. It seems that water is draining out because that PVC gets over filled. It hasn't been over filled in one year. What would cause it to overfill now. Only thing that changed is the new toilet I put in. Maybe the flush pressure is high in that toilet?

Comment: Drain lines aren't pressurized, they just drain by gravity to a sewage system, and are vented to atmosphere. That's why, even with the trap, it's strange that you're seeing this problem. Its also why I'd be comfortable with my solution... Although there is some transient pressure built up, it can't be very much and is surely quickly dissipated.

Comment: ok, I'm taking your suggestion of sealing one step ahead. I'm replacing that PVC to 3 inch pipe without any vent (since I assume there is no need for vent here). one end will take the plastic line (from the softner) and the other end will just go in the drain. Does that make sense?

Comment: I'm not sure about the vent... On one hand, the softener doesn't drain a lot, but on the other hand, washing machines are essentially vented in their drains. I would guess that the plumbing code would actually tell you that you need a vent here,but I'm not sure it causes any real problems if you don't have one.

Comment: The 'vent's prob an [air gap](http://www.plbg.com/forum/read.php?1,428234).

Comment: @Mazura Thanks! reading up on that tells me that the "vent" was important in this case because if it was not there then the waste water would have gotten into the water softener. Based on my research I've told the plumber to not proceed with the work. I will call a plumber who knows a thing or two about water softeners.